# Zend comparison operation style

Tags: php, zend-framework, comparison

This may not be an important issue but it bugs me anytime(quite often) I come across it, so I need to put my mind to rest. Please bear with me.

I am more used to seeing and using comparison operations like this:

```
if($some_var ==NULL){}
```

But Zend documentation(and only in zend do I notice this) always reverses the operands:

```
if(NULL ==$some_var){}
```

I'm not a computer scientist, so I would like to know if the order of these operands matter. Is there a difference or reason why zend documentation chooses the reverse style?

Comment: i've seen these being called 'yoda conditionals' :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is the same. The advantage of this approach is what happens if the programmer accidentally types one equals instead of two:

```
if ($some_var = NULL) // this will perform an assignment instead of a comparison

if (NULL = $some_var) // this will give you a parse error
```

so it helps prevent those kinds of coding mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the Zend style for one reason.  If you accidentally type `=` instead of `==` or `===` you will get an error.  In the variable-first format, you will silently assign that value to your variable.